# Guidance on executing queries from UI layer

Tags: .net, architecture, domain-driven-design, data-access-layer

I'm trying to establish a convention on how to execute queries from our UI (controllers) layer. Here are my three options:

1. Wrap each query into its own query object. (seems to lead to class explosion but better encapsulation).
2. Provide a service facade layer in order to group related queries together. (breaks SRP and sprinkles caching throughout. caching decorator makes more painful when not all query methods need caching.)
3. Provide an IDbReadContext that wraps EF or whatever. (exposes IQueryable which could or couldn't be bad. also gives no one point of caching since multiple objects could be running the same queries.

Any guidance or suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use a class per query, as I find several advantages to it. Each query class follows the single responsibility principle better, but also follows the open-closed principle better as well - it is easier to make changes in a system by adding new code and not changing existing code when each query is encapsulated in its own class. It is also easier to systematically apply cross-cutting behaviors like logging, authorization, and caching using aspect-oriented techniques when each query is its own class.

On occasion, I will design a single query class with multiple overloads for calling the query with different sets of parameters, but I try to do this only when the result is logically the same only retrieved from slightly different contexts - the amount of reusability between the overloads is a good indication of whet

Comment: that's essentially what i did with my IQuery<I,O> abstraction. im just getting lots of resistance from my team where each query requires three (sometimes four) classes (Input, Output, optional view model).

Comment: we had to relax the common rule of "one code artifact [class, interface, etc] per file" and it took several iterations of folder/file organization strategies before we were able to cope well with the additional classes.  In particular, the .net conventions of a "Models" directory and "Controllers" directory etc, did *not* work well.  We had to make functional areas the primary division of folders at a high level.  So in a web project, we may have directories for Accounts, Users, Products, etc. and underneath those we have subdirectories for models, controller, query, commands, events, etc.

Comment: so funny, that's exactly how we got it setup as well and i (we) like it! do you let your application/business layer call the query classes or is that for UI purposes only?

Comment: Yes, but as little as necessary.  We try to take cues from CQRS and design in such a way that when a command is submitted little or no querying is needed, only modification. Queries used for view models return a variety of information, whereas queries for business logic usually return just a set of ids or a single value (often bool or an enum).